# Posting data from html to flask view using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I have a dropdown that I am using. Here is the **HTML**:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static',filename='dropdown_change.js')}}"></script>


 <form action="{{url_for('select_ID')}}" method="POST">
  <label for="input_ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="Node_Type">Node_Type</label>
  <select id="dropdown_change">
    <option value=1>Customer</option>
    <option value=2>Phone</option>
    <option value=3>ID_Card</option>
  </select>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Here is my flask view:

```
import db_connect_test
from db_connect_test import Viz_Connector
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash,json,jsonify
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def select_ID():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ID=request.form['input_ID']
        Node_Type = request.form['Node_Type']
        data = Viz_Connector(ID,Node_type).get_data()
        return  render_template('dropdown.html',data=json.dumps(data))


    return render_template('dropdown.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.getenv('IP','0.0.0.0')
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT',5000))
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(host=host,port=port)
```

Here is my jquery for the drop down. There is a event listenere for "clicking" of the submit button. I think the way I am hand

```
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
   var ID = $("#input_ID").val();
   var selectID = $("#dropdown_change").val();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/select_ID",

     data: {
       ID: ID,
       Node_Type: selectID  //right way to pass the data to flask?
     },
     success: function(data) {
       alert('SUCCESS: ' + data);
     },
     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       document.getElementById('dropdown_change').selectedIndex = 0;
       showMsg('ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
       return false;
     }
   });
   return false;
 });
```

When I run this it fails with:

```
   400:Bad request
```

Comment: @lix URL corresponds to the "select_ID" function in flask.

Comment: I think you are missing #input_ID on the text input. Have you checked JS console for error?

Comment: You need to reconcile the variable names as well. The simplest way is to match up all of the HTML IDs to the posted form values.

Comment: @dana I think they are reconciled now and I did see something you posted in the answer section but it is gone now.

Comment: @optimus_prime - OK, I un-deleted my answer.  You may have a couple additional things to cleanup, but pointed out at least a few issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url-encode your data before sending it to the server.  Also, your routing will not pickup a `POST` to the path `/select_ID`.  You should be posting to `/` instead.  A slightly slicker way to do this is to read the `action` attribute in jQuery.

HTML:

```
<form action="{{url_for('select_ID')}}" method="POST">
    <label for="input_ID">ID</label>
    <input id="input_ID" type="text" />
    <label for="Node_Type">Node_Type</label>
    <select id="Node_Type">
        <option value=1>Customer</option>
        <option value=2>Phone</option>
        <option value=3>ID_Card</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    var input_ID= $("#input_ID").val();
    var Node_Type= $("#Node_Type").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).closest("form").attr("action"), // read the URL from the form attribute
        data: $.param({ // use $.param() to convert from a JSON object to url-encoded
            input_ID: input_ID,
            Node_Type: Node_Type
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('SUCCESS: ' + data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            document.getElementById('Node_Type').selectedIndex = 0;
            showMsg('ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

NOTE: Per my comment above, I reconciled the HTML IDs and JavaScript variables to use `input_ID` and `Node_Type` since this is what is expected on the server.

Comment: Hi , it is not able to complete the "GET" request and fails with:
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'static' instead?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe you want to leave in `{{url_for('select_ID')}}` after all, but leave the modified JavaScript code as is.  I will update my answer.

Comment: So , now it does work but it goes to the url: http://172.31.179.196:5000/form%20action= and gives a 404 NOT found. It should ideally connect with the back end db and render a graph. All I need to confirm is that is this a separate error related to the back end db or linked one?

Comment: The browser is redirected? That does not make any sense since the button click event is being cancelled and jQuery is being used to send the data to the server. I don't see any JavaScript redirects either. Have you tried inspecting the request using a tool like Fiddler? It might give you a better idea of what is actually being sent to the server and the response that is being generated.

Comment: First GET request happens at 172.31.179.196:5000. After the POST the url changes to 172.31.179.196:5000/form%20action=.. So it is not redirecting.

Comment: Ignore that error. That was due to a typo in HTML on my system. But even after trying your solution I still get 400: Bad request.

Comment: Thanks a ton. got it to work. The problem was the placement of the <script type= "javascript"> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your route:

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def select_ID():
```

to

```
@app.route('/select_ID',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def select_ID():
```